# Acceleration logic with Vector3

Tags: java, libgdx, logic, game-physics

I'm trying to get this `Vector3` to accelerate when it's to the right and decelerate when it's not. This is my update method. Why doesn't it accelerate? It has a constant speed. I know you could just add -5 to `vel.x`if it's to the left and +5 if it's to the right and then stop it when `vel.x` is 0 but I'm trying to make this work. I really don't understand what it is I'm doing wrong.

In the class I have declared two `Vector3`s (used in `update`)

```
    public void update(float delta) {
        timePassed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //irrelevant

        if (pos.x > Kiwi.WIDTH / 2)
            vel.add(-5, 0, 0);

        vel.x *= 0.8f;

        vel.scl(delta);
        pos.add(vel.x, 0, 0);
        vel.scl(1 / delta);
    }
```

Comment: I only want `vel.add(-5,0,0);` in the `if`. Nothing else. When it's to the left I want it to decelerate again. What more context do you need? This is the whole update method for this screen atm. When the `vector` is on the right half of the screen I want it to accelerate, otherwise decelerate. 
Do I make sense? Tell me if I don't.

Comment: If I remove the `velx*=0.8f;` it accelerates as intended but obviously it doesn't decelerate after it reaches the middle of the screen, it continues with a constant speed.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. I greatly appreciate your help. I updated my question and included the full update method. The way it currently looks should make it accelerate, right? Note that `ACC` equals -3.

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear. The first edit is what I changed the update method to after reading your answer. I now included the update method as it looked from the beginning.

Comment: In my code I am using tutorialVel and tutorialPos but to make it easier to understand I changed it to vel and pos respectively in here. I forgot to edit that single tutorialVel.x to a vel.x by mistake when posting it here.

Comment: I have edited your question to become clearer and removed my comments in that light. Also updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer

```
public void update(float delta) {
    if (pos.x > Kiwi.WIDTH / 2)
        vel.add(-5, 0, 0);
    vel.x *= 0.8f;
    vel.scl(delta);
    pos.add(vel.x, 0, 0);
    vel.scl(1 / delta);
}
```

The update method is called once for every frame. So what happens with your code above is that you reduce the velocity by 20% every frame, meaning if you have 60FPS, you will reduce your velocity to `0.8^60 = 1.eE-6` or practically zero in one second when you're to the left half of the screen.

You also want to to accelerate when it is to the right... Accelerate in which direction?  What you're doing now is that if the position is to the RIGHT half of the screen, then it accelerates to the LEFT meaning as soon as you get to the RIGHT half it moves back to the LEFT! Change `-5` to `+5` and then it will fly off because you're increasing speed by `5*60=300 px/s^2`. You need to scale the acceleration by the time delta.

Also you will need to scale the deacceleration by the time delta too. The divide by delta (`1/delta`) doesn't make any sense either so try this:

```
public void update(float delta) {
    if (pos.x > Kiwi.WIDTH / 2)
        vel.add(5*delta, 0, 0); // Acceleration is now 5 px/s^2 to the right
    vel.x -= vel.x*0.2f*delta; // Decay speed by 20% every second
    pos.add(vel.x*delta, 0, 0); // Move position by speed.
}
```

### Old answer below

Without more code to go on, all I can do is show you the correct way to do the calculations in the general case.

If you want to use a Euler's method for solving the motion ODEs this is how you do it:

```
// Object state
speed = ...; // Unit is [m/s]
position = ...; // Unit is [m]   


// Inputs
frameDelta = ...; // Unit is [s]
acceleration = ...; // Unit is [m/s^2]

// Update step
speed += acceleration * frameDelta; // Unit [m/s^2 * s] = [m/s];
position += speed * frameDelta; // Unit [m/s * s] = [m]
```

If you want the speed to "decay" you can do it by adding a suitable deacceleration (or drag/wind resistance/friction whatever you want to call it):

```
decayRate = ...; // Unit is [m/(m*s^2) = 1/s^2] ((de)acceleration per meter)
acceleration -= speed * decayRate * frameDelta; // Unit is [m/s*1/s^2*s = m/s]
```

Note: that you do not store the acceleration, you compute it each frame from other inputs (keyboard, mouse, forces, collisions etc).

Note2: Euler's method is the easiest solver you can use to compute the position and speed from acceleration. It comes with some problems, it is not as accurate as for example Runge-Kutta and it can also exhibit some stability issues with the oscillation.

You know when you see something shaking like it's crazy when it is stuck in a game? Yeah, that's probably Euler's method becoming unstable.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me. I think I solved it now.